# VRML: Prevent avatar from collision

Tags: javascript, graphics, virtual, augmented-reality, vrml

I am designing a simple game using VRML V2.0.
But there is a problem. I need to create an avatar and allow this avatar to move. Then create walls and exhibit the avatar from crossing the walls using collision detection and prevention.
But how to detect and prevent such collisions?
What is available is to detect collisions by the viewers and the shapes using the Collision node which does not satisfy my requirements.
I need to detect collisions between a shape and a shape so I will move a shape and if it hit another shape, collision occur.

Answer (score 0):

Parallel graphics [built an extension](http://www.parallelgraphics.com/developer/products/cortona/extensions/collision) to VRML - but it was some time ago.